# Can we get a $\LaTeX$ button?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, mathjax, user-interface

I would like to propose the addition of a $\LaTeX$ button. It would be very similar to the "code" button that formats the highlighted text into code, the $\LaTeX$ button would surround the highlighted text in `$....$`. This would make life a lot easier when you are editing posts.

What do you think about this?

EDIT:

I am thinking about building a very small java application for the time being that will allow you to press, for example, `CTRL +1` and it will surround the text in `$..$`. Will people be interested in using such an application?

Comment: I'd go even further and request a nice keyboard shortcut as well. If it's not too much trouble to add to the system, of course...

Comment: @J.M. Yes, definitely. If this feature is implementable then a keyboard shortcut would also make a lot of sense.

Comment: Shift + (4 4) - it's in my blood.

Comment: Could this not be solved by a browser plug-in? (Which would, of course, be required to be written by someone. However, if what @75064 points out is true, that "this idea [won't get] any further than "Type: Enhancement | Status: New | Priority: Low" on the Pagedown issues list", then this seems like the only solution...)

Comment: @user1729 Browser plug-in ... That is a very good idea. I hadn't thought about that. Maybe if the answer suggested by 75054 doesn't get "chosen" then we can opt for that.

Comment: This has an added benefit of alerting new users to the existence of $\LaTeX$.

Comment: I prefer typing the dollar signs explicitly. This doesn’t mean that it shouldn’t be done; it just means that I see no need for it and wouldn’t use it.

Comment: @J.M. I have one. MIDI Keyboard + Max/MSP or Bome's MIDI Translator.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I like the idea. When entering a long post with many formulas, the constant re-rendering of MathJax can be a drag on the browser; in such cases it is preferable to type formulas first and add `$ $` later. Having a button/shortcut for this would be handy. Ideally, it would loop between `text`, `$text$`, and `$$text$$`, like the current Ctrl+I shortcut loops between `text` and `*text*`.

Drawing in an extra button takes a designer's effort but is not a big obstacle: button images differ between sites already. For example:

Math.SE editor buttons    [image: mse buttons]

Travel.SE editor buttons   [image: travel buttons]

The bigger deal is the script that handles the button clicks and keyboard shortcuts, along with all Markdown processing. It currently stands at $2459$ lines of JavaScript code named `wmd.js` (not [WMD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weapon_of_mass_destruction)). Officially called [Pagedown](https://code.google.com/p/pagedown/wiki/PageDown), it is being developed by SE as an open-source project. At some point of its history, it was reverse-engineered from seemingly abandoned obfuscated code (the original author could never be contacted again). See:

- [Reverse Engineering the WMD Editor](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/12/reverse-engineering-the-wmd-editor/)
- [WMD Editor Reverse Engineered](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/wmd-editor-reverse-engineered/)
- [Updated WMD Editor](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/updated-wmd-editor/)

The editor is the same on all SE sites; maintaining separate versions would be rather painful, I imagine. But there is no need for that; the script can determine if the site has MathJax enabled, and activate the button and shortcut in this case only:

```
 if (StackExchange.mathjaxEditing) { enable $ button and shortcut }
```

Done! :) And it's now $2460$ lines of code.

Comment: That said, I'll be surprised if this idea gets any further than "Type: Enhancement | Status: New | Priority: Low" on the [Pagedown issues list](https://code.google.com/p/pagedown/issues/list).

Comment: If that is the case then do you think there is a way to create some sort of plugin in Firefox/Chrome?